Calculate azimuth and pitch angle from total angle and direction
I am looking for a way to compute the azimuth and pitch angles from a system where I only know the total angle and I know the circular direction of the angle.
Let $a =$ azimuth angle and $b =$ pitch angle. Then I found that
$$\text{Total Angle} = \arccos(\cos(a)\cos(b))$$
I also know angular direction (clock direction) is related to $\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$. In my computation I’m utilizing the atan2 function and adding 180 or 360 depending on the quadrant.
So knowing these two values how can I compute $a$ and $b$ efficiently?

$\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$ is a completely useless number in this exercise. You can use the atan2 function but you need different input.

Your question is equivalent to the following:
Starting at zero latitude and zero longitude on a sphere of radius $1$, travel a distance $\delta$ in the compass direction $\psi$. What latitude $\phi$ and longitude $\lambda$ do you reach?
Latitude and longitude are pitch (or elevation) and azimuth respectively.
Total angle (in radians) is the distance traveled and
clock direction corresponds to compass direction at the start.
You just have to be careful to account for differences between how you define your clock direction and how compass direction is normally defined.
For the usual definition of compass direction, the formulas (adapted from The Aviation Formulary) are:
\begin{align}
     \phi &=\arcsin(\sin(\delta)\cos(\psi)),\\
     \lambda &=\operatorname{atan2}(\sin(\delta)\sin(\psi),\cos(\delta))
\end{align}

An alternative approach is to consider the total angle/clock direction scheme as a kind of spherical coordinate system
and the azimuth and pitch as a different spherical coordinate system.
In the first system, you have a pole on one axis (presumably in a horizontal plane),
the total angle is measured from the pole (it is a "co-latitude" in this coordinate system), and the clock direction is the "longitude" coordinate.
In the second system, you have a pole on another axis (presumably perpendicular to the horizontal plane), pitch is measured as an angle from the equator (positive in the direction toward the pole) and azimuth is the "longitude" coordinate.
Make an axis perpendicular to the two axes you already have.
Now you have three axes of a Cartesian coordinate system.
Given a total angle and clock direction,
assume they are coordinates in the first spherical coordinate system,
convert them to the Cartesian coordinate system,
then convert the Cartesian coordinates to coordinates in
the second spherical coordinate system.
If you write these steps using symbols for the angles you should be able to derive formulas for pitch and azimuth similar to the formulas shown above.

That's what I needed. Makes sense I should have thought about it like compass navigation.
